# Finding Identity Element for given operation

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

I'm beginner in Group Theory and learning it by following 'Pinter algebra'

I just want to verify if my thought process is correct in following exercise

> $(a, b)\times(c, d) = (a \cdot c, b \cdot c + d)$, on the set **R * R** does this form
>   group ? If not, Give reason why it doesn't form a Group

ans: NO

reason: some elements don't have inverse element  and **not because it doesn't have identity element**

**My question is does above one have identity element w.r.t to $\times$?**

- Checking for Right Identity

  $(a,b) \times (x,y)=( a\ \cdot x, b \cdot x+y )=(a,b)$

  $a \cdot x = a \rightarrow a(1-x)=0: a=0$ or $x=1$

  but for this to be true for all '$a$', so $x=1$

  $b \cdot x+y =b$

  substituting $x=1$

  $b+y=b \rightarrow y=0$

  Right Identity is $(x,y)=(1,0)$
- Checking for Left Identity

  $(x,y) \times (a,b)=(x \cdot a, y \cdot a+b)=(a,b)$

  $x \cdot a=a \rightarrow a(1-x)=0 \rightarrow a=0$ or $x=1$

  but for this to be true for all 'a'  $x=1$

  $y \cdot a+b=b \rightarrow y \cdot a=0 \rightarrow  y=0$ or $a=0$

  but for this to be true all '$a$', so $y=0$

  Left Identity is $(x,y)=(1,0)$

**Therefore it has $(1,0)$ as identity element**

Comment: Yes, this seems correct.

Comment: @idok thanks.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.

For similar phenomena, consider studying semigroup theory, where there can exist an identity but no inverses.